# How to add cell numbers to Visual Studio Code / Jupyter Notebook for Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

**Using:**

MacBook Pro (Ventura 13.3.1)

Visual Studio Code 1.78.2

Jupyter extension v2023.4.1011241018

**Question:**

I know how to enable *line* numbers within each cell, but I cannot figure out how to enable *cell* numbers (or IDs) within the notebook. How can I show *cell* numbers in the notebook?

The screenshot below shows an example - the red text is an example of what the number or ID of the cell itself would look like.

**Screenshot example:**

[image]